# Polynomial equation in two variables

Tags: polynomials

Let $k[x,y]$ be the polynomial ring where $k$ is a field. Let $f,g,h \in k[x,y]$. Consider the following equality.

$f \cdot (x-y)^2 - g \cdot (x+y)^2 = h \cdot x^2$

If $h \neq 0$, can we say that either $f$ or $g$ must contain a multiple of $x^2$?

It looks correct to me since $x^2$ divide neither $(x-y)^2$ nor $(x+y)^2$ but I couldn't be completely sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(x-y)^2$ means $(x-y)^2f$ and not $f((x-y)^2)$ or $(f(x-y))^2$?

Comment: yes, just multiplication of polynomials. The question is edited!

Comment: If $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=x$, then $(x-y)^2f-(x+y)^2g=-4x^2y$.

Comment: Nice and easy answer! thanks!